# [__NSCFString setPosition:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I'm using one plugin for scrollable layer. It has two files as shown below.

**FGScrollLayer.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"

@class FGScrollLayer;
@protocol FGScrollLayerDelegate

@optional

/** Called when scroll layer begins scrolling.
 * Usefull to cancel CCTouchDispatcher standardDelegates.
 */
- (void) scrollLayerScrollingStarted:(FGScrollLayer *) sender;

/** Called at the end of moveToPage:
 */
- (void) scrollLayer: (FGScrollLayer *) sender scrolledToPageNumber: (int) page;

@end

/** Vertical scrolling layer for items.
 *
 * It is a very clean and elegant subclass of CCLayer that lets you pass-in an array
 * of layers and it will then create a smooth scroller.
 * Every sub-layer should have the same size in current version.
 *
 * @version 0.1.01
 */
@interface FGScrollLayer : CCLayer
{
    NSObject <FGScrollLayerDelegate> *delegate_;

    // The screen coord of initial point the user starts their swipe.
    CGFloat startSwipe_;

    // The coord of initial position the user starts their swipe.
    CGFloat startSwipeLayerPos_;

    // For what distance user must slide finger to start scrolling menu.
    CGFloat minimumTouchLengthToSlide_;

    // Internal state of scrollLayer (scrolling or idle).
    int state_;

    BOOL stealTouches_;

#ifdef __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED
    // Holds the touch that started the scroll
    UITouch *scrollTouch_;
#endif

    // Holds pages.
    NSMutableArray *layers_;

    // Holds current pages width offset.
    CGFloat pagesOffset_;

    // Holds the height of every page
    CGFloat pageHeight_;

    // Holds the width of every page
    CGFloat pageWidth_;

    // Holds the maximum upper position
    CGFloat maxVerticalPos_;

    // Holds the real responsible rect in the screen
    CGRect realBound;

    /*Decoration and slide bars*/
    // Scroll bars on the right
    CCSprite* scrollBar;
    CGFloat scrollBarPosY;

    // Scroll block that indicates the current position in whole scorll view content
    CCSprite* scrollBlock;
    CGFloat scrollBlockUpperBound;
    CGFloat scrollBlockLowerBound;

    // Decoration
    // Holds position to maintain their position fixed even in setPosition
    CCSprite* upperBound;
    CGFloat upperBoundPosY;
    CCSprite* lowerBound;
    CGFloat lowerBoundPosY;
}

@property (readwrite, assign) NSObject <FGScrollLayerDelegate> *delegate;

#pragma mark Scroll Config Properties

/** Calibration property. Minimum moving touch length that is enough
 * to cancel menu items and start scrolling a layer.
 */
@property(readwrite, assign) CGFloat minimumTouchLengthToSlide;

/** If YES - when starting scrolling FGScrollLayer will claim touches, that are
 * already claimed by others targetedTouchDelegates by calling CCTouchDispatcher#touchesCancelled
 * Usefull to have ability to scroll with touch above menus in pages.
 * If NO - scrolling will start, but no touches will be cancelled.
 * Default is YES.
 */
@property(readwrite) BOOL stealTouches;

#pragma mark Pages Control Properties

/** Offset, that can be used to let user see next/previous page. */
@property(readwrite) CGFloat pagesOffset;

/** Page height, this version requires that each page shares the same height and width */
@property(readonly) CGFloat pageHeight;
@property(readonly) CGFloat pageWidth;

/** Returns array of pages CCLayer's  */
@property(readonly) NSArray *pages;
- (void) updatePages;
-(void)updatePagesAvailability;
#pragma mark Init/Creation

/** Creates new scrollLayer with given pages & width offset.
 * @param layers NSArray of CCLayers, that will be used as pages.
 * @param pageSize indicates the size of every page, now this version requires each page 
 * share the same page size
 * @param widthOffset Length in X-coord, that describes length of possible pages
 * @param visibleRect indicates the real position and size on the screen
 * intersection. */
+(id) nodeWithLayers:(NSArray *)layers pageSize:(CGSize)pageSize pagesOffset: (int) pOffset visibleRect: (CGRect)rect;

/** Inits scrollLayer with given pages & width offset.
 * @param layers NSArray of CCLayers, that will be used as pages.
 * @param pageSize indicates the size of every page, now this version requires each page
 * share the same page size
 * @param pagesOffset Length in X-coord, that describes length of possible pages
 * @param visibleRect indicates the real position and size on the screen
 * intersection. */
-(id) initWithLayers:(NSArray *)layers pageSize:(CGSize)pageSize pagesOffset: (int) pOffset visibleRect: (CGRect)rect;

#pragma mark Misc
/**
 * Return the number of pages
 */
-(int) totalPagesCount;

#pragma mark Moving/Selecting Pages

/* Moves scrollLayer to page with given number.
 * Does nothing if number >= totalScreens or < 0.
 */
-(void) moveToPage:(int)page;

@end
```

**FGScrollLayer.m**

```
//
//  FGScrollLayer.m
//  Fall G
//
//  Created by Dai Xuefeng on 23/9/12.
//  Copyright 2012 Nofootbird. 
//

#import "FGScrollLayer.h"


enum
{
    kFGScrollLayerStateIdle,
    kFGScrollLayerStateSliding,
};

#ifdef __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED
@interface CCTouchDispatcher (targetedHandlersGetter)

- (id<NSFastEnumeration>) targetedHandlers;

@end

@implementation CCTouchDispatcher (targetedHandlersGetter)

- (id<NSFastEnumeration>) targetedHandlers
{
    return targetedHandlers;
}

@end
#endif

@implementation FGScrollLayer

@synthesize delegate = delegate_;
@synthesize minimumTouchLengthToSlide = minimumTouchLengthToSlide_;
@synthesize pagesOffset = pagesOffset_;
@synthesize pages = layers_;
@synthesize stealTouches = stealTouches_;
@synthesize pageHeight = pageHeight_;
@synthesize pageWidth = pageWidth_;

- (int) totalPagesCount
{
    return [layers_ count];
}

+(id) nodeWithLayers:(NSArray *)layers pageSize:(CGSize)pageSize pagesOffset:(int)pOffset visibleRect:(CGRect)rect{
    return [[[self alloc] initWithLayers: layers pageSize:pageSize pagesOffset:pOffset visibleRect:rect] autorelease];
}

-(id) initWithLayers:(NSArray *)layers pageSize:(CGSize)pageSize pagesOffset:(int)pOffset visibleRect:(CGRect)rect{
    if ( (self = [super init]) )
    {
        NSAssert([layers count], @"FGScrollLayer#initWithLayers:widthOffset: you must provide at least one layer!");

        // Enable Touches/Mouse.
#ifdef __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED
        self.isTouchEnabled = YES;
#endif

        self.stealTouches = YES;

        // Set default minimum touch length to scroll.
        self.minimumTouchLengthToSlide = 30.0f;

        // Save offset.
        self.pagesOffset = pOffset;

        // Save array of layers.
        layers_ = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:layers copyItems:NO];

        // Save pages size for later calculation
        pageHeight_ = pageSize.height;
        pageWidth_ = pageSize.width;
        maxVerticalPos_ = pageHeight_ * [layers_ count] - rect.size.height + 5;

        realBound = rect;

        [self updatePages];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) dealloc
{
    self.delegate = nil;

    [layers_ release];
    layers_ = nil;

    [super dealloc];
}

- (void) updatePages
{
    // Loop through the array and add the screens if needed.
    int i = 0;
    for (CCLayer *l in layers_)
    {
        l.position = ccp(realBound.origin.x,  realBound.origin.y + (realBound.size.height - i * (pageHeight_ - self.pagesOffset)));
        if (!l.parent){
            [self addChild:l];
        }

        i++;
    }
    [self updatePagesAvailability];
}

/**
 * According to current position, decide which pages are visible
 */
-(void)updatePagesAvailability{
    CGPoint currentPos = [self position];
    if (currentPos.y > 0) {
        int visibleBoundUp = currentPos.y / pageHeight_;
        visibleBoundUp = MIN([layers_ count], visibleBoundUp);
        for (int i = 0; i < visibleBoundUp; i++) {
            [[layers_ objectAtIndex:i] setVisible:NO];
        }
        if (visibleBoundUp < [layers_ count]) {
            int visibleBoundDown = (currentPos.y + realBound.size.height) / pageHeight_;
            visibleBoundDown = MIN([layers_ count] - 1, visibleBoundDown);
            for (int i = visibleBoundUp; i <= visibleBoundDown; i++) {
                [[layers_ objectAtIndex:i] setVisible:YES];
            }
            if (visibleBoundDown < [layers_ count] - 1) {
                for (int i = visibleBoundDown + 1; i <= [layers_ count] - 1; i++) {
                    [[layers_ objectAtIndex:i] setVisible:NO];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else if (currentPos.y <= 0){
        CGFloat gapY = -currentPos.y;
        int visibleBound = (realBound.size.height - gapY) / pageHeight_;
        // index visibleBound itself should be invisible
        if (visibleBound < 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < [layers_ count]; i++) {
                [[layers_ objectAtIndex:i] setVisible:NO];
            }
            return;
        }
        visibleBound = MIN([layers_ count] - 1, visibleBound);
        for (int i = 0; i <= visibleBound; i++) {
            [[layers_ objectAtIndex:i] setVisible:YES];
        }
        for (int i = visibleBound + 1; i < [layers_ count]; i++) {
            [[layers_ objectAtIndex:i] setVisible:NO];
        }
    }
}

-(void)setRealBound:(CGPoint)position size:(CGPoint)size{
    realBound = CGRectMake(position.x, position.y, size.x, size.y);
}

-(void)setPosition:(CGPoint)position{
    [super setPosition:position];
    [self updatePagesAvailability];
    CGFloat scrollBlockDesiredY = scrollBlockUpperBound - (scrollBlockUpperBound - scrollBlockLowerBound) * position.y / maxVerticalPos_;
    if (scrollBlockDesiredY > scrollBlockUpperBound) {
        scrollBlockDesiredY = scrollBlockUpperBound;
    }else if (scrollBlockDesiredY < scrollBlockLowerBound){
        scrollBlockDesiredY = scrollBlockLowerBound;
    }
    [scrollBlock setPosition:ccp([scrollBlock position].x, scrollBlockDesiredY - position.y)];
    [lowerBound setPosition:ccp([lowerBound position].x, lowerBoundPosY - position.y)];
    [upperBound setPosition:ccp([upperBound position].x, upperBoundPosY - position.y)];
    [scrollBar setPosition:ccp([scrollBar position].x, scrollBarPosY - position.y)];
}

#pragma mark Moving To / Selecting Pages

-(void) moveToPage:(int)page
{
    if (page < 0 || page >= [layers_ count]) {
        CCLOGERROR(@"FGScrollLayer#moveToPage: %d - wrong page number, out of bounds. ", page);
        return;
    }

    CGFloat desiredPos = page * pageHeight_;
    if (desiredPos > maxVerticalPos_) {
        desiredPos = maxVerticalPos_;
    }

    [self runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.3 position:ccp([self position].x, desiredPos)]];

}

#pragma mark Touches
#ifdef __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED

/** Register with more priority than CCMenu's but don't swallow touches. */
-(void) registerWithTouchDispatcher
{
#if COCOS2D_VERSION >= 0x00020000
    CCTouchDispatcher *dispatcher = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] touchDispatcher];
    int priority = kCCMenuHandlerPriority - 1;
#else
    CCTouchDispatcher *dispatcher = [CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher];
    int priority = kCCMenuTouchPriority - 1;
#endif

    [dispatcher addTargetedDelegate:self priority: priority swallowsTouches:NO];
}

/** Hackish stuff - stole touches from other CCTouchDispatcher targeted delegates.
 Used to claim touch without receiving ccTouchBegan. */
- (void) claimTouch: (UITouch *) aTouch
{
#if COCOS2D_VERSION >= 0x00020000
    CCTouchDispatcher *dispatcher = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] touchDispatcher];
#else
    CCTouchDispatcher *dispatcher = [CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher];
#endif

    // Enumerate through all targeted handlers.
    for ( CCTargetedTouchHandler *handler in [dispatcher targetedHandlers] )
    {
        // Only our handler should claim the touch.
        if (handler.delegate == self)
        {
            if (![handler.claimedTouches containsObject: aTouch])
            {
                [handler.claimedTouches addObject: aTouch];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Steal touch from other targeted delegates, if they claimed it.
            if ([handler.claimedTouches containsObject: aTouch])
            {
                if ([handler.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(ccTouchCancelled:withEvent:)])
                {
                    [handler.delegate ccTouchCancelled: aTouch withEvent: nil];
                }
                [handler.claimedTouches removeObject: aTouch];
            }
        }
    }
}

-(void)ccTouchCancelled:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [scrollBar setVisible:NO];
    [scrollBlock setVisible:NO];

    if( scrollTouch_ == touch ) {
        scrollTouch_ = nil;
    }
}

// these two variables are to make a sliding effect on scroll view
static CGFloat previousTouchPointY = -1;
static CGFloat moveSpeed = 0;
-(BOOL) ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if( scrollTouch_ == nil ) {
        scrollTouch_ = touch;
    } else {
        return NO;
    }

    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
    touchPoint = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:touchPoint];

    startSwipe_ = touchPoint.y;
    startSwipeLayerPos_ = [self position].y;
    state_ = kFGScrollLayerStateIdle;
    return YES;
}

- (void)ccTouchMoved:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if( scrollTouch_ != touch ) {
        return;
    }

    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
    touchPoint = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:touchPoint];


    // If finger is dragged for more distance then minimum - start sliding and cancel pressed buttons.
    // Of course only if we not already in sliding mode
    if ( (state_ != kFGScrollLayerStateSliding)
        && (fabsf(touchPoint.y-startSwipe_) >= self.minimumTouchLengthToSlide) )
    {
        state_ = kFGScrollLayerStateSliding;

        // Avoid jerk after state change.
        startSwipe_ = touchPoint.y;
        startSwipeLayerPos_ = [self position].y;
        previousTouchPointY = touchPoint.y;

        if (self.stealTouches)
        {
            [self claimTouch: touch];
        }

        if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(scrollLayerScrollingStarted:)])
        {
            [self.delegate scrollLayerScrollingStarted: self];
        }
    }

    if (state_ == kFGScrollLayerStateSliding)
    {
        CGFloat desiredY = startSwipeLayerPos_ + touchPoint.y - startSwipe_;
        [self setPosition:ccp(0, desiredY)];

        // enable scroll bar to be visible
        [scrollBar setVisible:YES];
        [scrollBlock setVisible:YES];

        // update scrolling effect variables
        moveSpeed = touchPoint.y - previousTouchPointY;
        previousTouchPointY = touchPoint.y;
    }
}

/**
 * After touching, generate an inertia effect.
 */
- (void)moveToDesiredPos:(CGFloat)desiredY{
    CCAction* slidingAction = nil;
    if (desiredY > maxVerticalPos_) {
        slidingAction = [CCSequence actions:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.10 position:ccp([self position].x, desiredY)], [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.15 position:ccp([self position].x, maxVerticalPos_)], nil];
    }
    else if (desiredY < 0){
        slidingAction = [CCSequence actions:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.10 position:ccp([self position].x, desiredY)],[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.15 position:ccp([self position].x, 0)], nil];
    }
    else{
        CGFloat interPosY = (desiredY - [self position].y) * 0.7 + [self position].y;
        slidingAction = [CCSequence actions:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.15 position:ccp([self position].x, interPosY)],[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.3 position:ccp([self position].x, desiredY)], nil];
    }
    [self runAction:slidingAction];
}

- (void)ccTouchEnded:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [scrollBar setVisible:NO];
    [scrollBlock setVisible:NO];

    if( scrollTouch_ != touch )
        return;
    scrollTouch_ = nil;

    if (ABS(moveSpeed) > 10) {
        CGFloat desiredDesY = [self position].y + moveSpeed * 5;
        [self moveToDesiredPos:desiredDesY];
    }
    else{
        if ([self position].y > maxVerticalPos_) {
            [self runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.3 position:ccp([self position].x, maxVerticalPos_)]];
        }else if ([self position].y < 0){
            [self runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.3 position:ccp([self position].x, 0)]];
        }
    }

    // restore scrolling effect variables to default value
    moveSpeed = 0;
    previousTouchPointY = -1;
}

#endif

@end
```

Now in my **HelloWorldLayer.m** init i do like Following:

```
-(id) init
{
    if( (self=[super init]) ) {
        NSMutableArray *persons = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            [persons addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]];
        }

        NSArray *arrayOfPersons = [NSArray arrayWithArray:persons];

        //scrollNode.position = ccp(0, 0);


        scrollNode = [FGScrollLayer nodeWithLayers:arrayOfPersons pageSize:CGSizeMake(100, 20) pagesOffset:1 visibleRect:CGRectMake(30, 30, 500, 900)];




    }
    return self;
}
```

But it is giving error:**-[__NSCFString setPosition:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x960e170**

I searched for this error and i came to know that it is **Fundamental Subclassing error.**,
Can anybody guide me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create an array of persons. They're all NSString objects. You pass that array (after needlessly copying it) into the scroll layer class which expects an array of CCLayer objects.